# Linq to populate field within same object

Tags: c#, linq

```
class Person
{
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IList<string> PersonCourseNames { get;set;}
}

class PersonCourse
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int PersonId {get;set; }  //reference key from Person
}
```

Having , IEnumerable  persons // where empty PersonCourseNames
and 
IEnumerable as list of PersonCourses

How to get result like,
List Of Person where PersonCourseNames are populated for matching PersonCourses.
//Need to poulate existing list of peersons

```
var combined = from p in Persons join c in PersonCourses on p.Id equals c.PersonId
select new {}  //here getting problem how to pouplate with list of course names
```

//notes: converted above `IEnumerable` to ToList().

Comment: Please post the code you've attempted yourself and the errors it was producing.

Comment: `Select(pc=>pc.Name).ToList()` ? eventually add `Where`

Comment: Can you elaborate more on *where PersonCourseNames are populated for matching PersonCourses.*? what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: added that what I tried with. issue with `select` clause.

Comment: hope its enought info.. apologies for initial post.

Comment: `Persons.ToList().ForEach(person => person.PersonCourseNames = personCourses.Where(course => course.PersonId.Equals(person.Id)).Select(course => course.Name).ToList());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//assuming you have those two
IEnumerable<Person> persons;
IEnumerable<PersonCourse> personCourses;

var personCoursesGroupedByPerson = personCourses.ToLookUp(x => x.PersonId, x => x.Name);
foreach (var person in persons)
     person.PersonCourseNames = personCoursesGroupedByPerson[person.Number].ToList();
```

This solution further assumes that `PersonCourse.PersonId` = `Person.Number`.

Here you can see an example:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/kW5Mep